# Merge field stored in custom setting

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, customsetting

Is it possible to store a merge field like `{!Account.Name}` as a custom setting, then reference the custom setting on a VisualForce page that uses the standard controller?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that but not in the way in which you are doing. I suggest you to use field API name and then refer that. In this way will you get expected output

```
{!reference[expression]}
```

Here reference is object and expression is your field.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf.htm)

Or you can store both object name and field name and then with some custom code use them in VF page

```
{!$ObjectType[objectType].fields[f].Label}
```

Where ObjectType is object and f stands for field.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm)

Comment: I am not trying to get the field name, I am trying to get the value of the field. I essentially want to store the merge field as a custom setting, this could be change so when displayed on the VF page it could change to be any field.

Comment: @developer__c label is just for reference. You can take any approach to display the value. Check the reference links for more details.

Comment: Just displays {!Account['Name']} on the page. This is being displayed as the literal string, rather than merging the actual value.

Comment: @developer__c if you use this on VF page then you will get Name of this account or if this name is stored in some string then this will also work  `{!Account[varName]}`